# Generations in garbage collection in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, clr

If the objects survived in the "Generation 2" and does not get removed in garbage collection, then what will happen?

Whether they will be promoted to any other further generation if it exists or they will remain in the same generation?

Please explain.

Comment: my understanding from this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx  is that Generation 2 will be cleaned up when the process ends (ideally)

Answer (score 3):

This objects keeps in the Generation 2. The oldest objects are at the lowest addresses, while new objects are created at increasing addresses.

Comment: "The oldest objects are at the lowest addresses" - I don't believe that statement is entirely correct. If the enough managed memory is allocated that the heap needs to grow, it will allocate a second region of virtual address space and there is no guarantee that that second region will be before or after the first (up to the operating system), leading to the possibility of a new object having a lower address than an earlier object.